# available gcc Cross Compiler RaspberriPi RHEL 8

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, rhel8

I wonder if there still exists a **not** deprecated cross compiler for raspberry pi. All I could find were old toolchains and deprecated cross compilers and almost everything wasn't available for RHEL8.
Does anybody know about an actual c/c++ cross compiler for RaspberryPi on RHEL?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: ? RHEL as any other system has a compiler, download the newest toolchain and compile it and install it. If you want to have newest packages, don't use RHEL, it is meant to have well tested products only, use a different distribution. Also docker.

Comment: thanks KamilCuk. If you refer to [link](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools), it says in the second line "These toolchains are deprecated. " and this is why I ask.

Comment: No, I do not refer to that link. There are prebuild toolchains available from https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads . The source code for gcc is available from https://gcc.gnu.org/ .

Comment: Thanks KamilCuk. This works great for me under eclipse. 
Just to mention, I also found xpack as an alternative, but I have no experience, so just to be mentioned, thius also exists